# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' USING GROUPBY

Tags: python, pandas, types

I want to sum in a GroupBy but I get this TypeError:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
df_gr = df_hu.groupby(['community', 'hour'])['totalCount'].sum()
```

I guess the reason is that I'm trying to sum a column ('totalCount') that is not int type.

```
df_hu.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 539208 entries, 0 to 22466
Data columns (total 3 columns):
hour          539208 non-null object
totalCount    539208 non-null object
community     396672 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 36.5+ MB
```

I have tried to use `astype()` and `to_numeric` for the column 'totalCount', but still not working.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Doing `df['totalCount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['totalCount'], errors='coerce')` will fix that problem, but then everything could be `NaN` depending upon the format

Comment: your code worked! thanks mate